# Secure UITextField textColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, textcolor

I have several `UITextFields` for registering a new account: name, password, etc. The password text field is Secure in the storyboard. The server returns validation information, such as if the password is too short, etc.

When a validation error is returned, I change the textColor of the appropriate `textField` to red to highlight that it has an error.

```
[messages enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *validationObj = (NSString*)key;
    NSArray *validationMsg = (NSArray*)obj;

    if ([validationObj isEqualToString:@"password"])
        self.registerFirstNameTextField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

When they start editing the text field, I change color back to black using an Action connected to the "`EditingChanged`" event of the `TextField`.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)sender;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

In Simulator (I have not tried this on a device), this works fine for all `textfields`, except for the Password text field. Specifically, when I edit the password `textfield`, it changes to black, but as soon as the `textfield` loses focus, the security dots are red. Any ideas why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. I had the exact same problem and solved it by forcing the textfield to the desired color when editing ended.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == passwordTextField) {
        [textField setTextColor:defaultTextColour];
}
```

Hope this helps!